# wifi direct create group failed

Tags: wifi-direct

my os is android 4.0.4,When I develop wifi direct, I create groups sometimes can succeed, sometimes failure, when after failure can cause the system to restart

The following is the error message after failure

```
01-01 11:31:30.003: DEBUG/NetworkManagementService(1331): flags <[down broadcast multicast]>
01-01 11:31:30.793: DEBUG/WifiP2pService(1331): P2p start successful
01-01 11:31:30.913: DEBUG/ViewRootImpl(1408): pckname = com.android.systemui
01-01 11:31:31.753: DEBUG/audio_hw_primary(1293): start_output_stream: card:0, port:0, rate:44100
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556): Update device info: Device: ID_9f68
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  deviceAddress: 00:09:01:55:18:49
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  interfaceAddress: null
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  primary type: 10-0050F204-5
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  secondary type: null
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  wps: 0
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  grpcapab: 0
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  devcapab: 0
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  status: 3
01-01 11:31:31.813: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  discover success
01-01 11:31:32.573: ERROR/WifiP2pService(1331): Unhandled message { what=147462 when=0 obj=android.net.wifi.StateChangeResult@410225f8 }
01-01 11:31:32.583: DEBUG/WifiP2pSettings(1556):  create group success
01-01 11:31:32.693: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(2438): Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 00:09:01:55:18:49 and ssid 'DIRECT-3p'
01-01 11:31:32.693: DEBUG/NetworkManagementService(1331): rsp <213 00:00:00:00:00:00 0.0.0.0 0 [up broadcast running multicast]>
01-01 11:31:32.703: DEBUG/NetworkManagementService(1331): flags <[up broadcast running multicast]>
01-01 11:31:33.013: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(2438): random: Cannot read from /dev/random: Try again
01-01 11:31:33.013: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(2438): WPA initialization failed.
01-01 11:31:33.013: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(2438): wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
01-01 11:31:33.013: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(2438): Failed to initialize AP interface
01-01 11:31:33.063: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(2438): Failed to remove interface (ifidx=27)
01-01 11:31:33.353: DEBUG/Tethering(1331): sendTetherStateChangedBroadcast 1, 0, 0
01-01 11:31:33.353: DEBUG/Tethering(1331): InitialState.processMessage what=4
01-01 11:31:33.353: DEBUG/Tethering(1331): sendTetherStateChangedBroadcast 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Looks like /dev/random wasn't available - which perhaps stopped the WPA certification from working. Did you find a fix? Got a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Wi-Fi Direct, only one group can exist at a time per device. To create a new group, the previous group must be terminated.

I faced the same problem in my app, and I solved it in this way: I made two buttons—one start and the other stop—I created a group on the start button, and removed the group on the stop button.

And I kept this thing for once. If you have created a group on the same device, you will have to remove the group before creating the group again.

[image]